# How can I purchase and play PAL games not available in my PAL country on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I have a PAL Xbox 360, purchased in the UK.  My console and profile settings are for the UK.

I wish to purchase a Games on Demand title from the marketplace that is available in Spanish and Italian marketplaces, but missing from the UK.

What steps do I need to take in order to *purchase* the game?

Will my PAL (UK) console/account be able to *play* a Spanish or Italian-specific game?

Comment: I'm not sure if you couldn't spin this question to be : "Are Spain and Italy PAL regions, like the UK is?". Because, if that's your issue, then you have no issue, as yes, Spain and Italy are PAL regions

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to internet with your Xbox by hooking a VPN on your router (or by setting up a proxy if your router doesn't support VPN connection). 
You can also use XBoxLive from windows and set up a VPN like described in [this guide](http://www.vpntraffic.com/index.php?action=content&cont_id=9875).

A VPN will allow you to make the xbox server think you're in another country, you're network will look like that :

[Your XBOX] ---- [Your Router (UK ip address)] =======Encrypted tunnel ======== [The VPN Server (Italian or wherever ip] ---------- [Xbox Live Server]

> (Wikipedia)
>   A virtual private network (VPN) extends a private network across a public network, such as the Internet. It enables users to send and receive data across shared or public networks as if their computing devices were directly connected to the private network, and thus are benefiting from the functionality, security and management policies of the private network.[1] A VPN is created by establishing a virtual point-to-point connection through the use of dedicated connections, virtual tunnelling protocols, or traffic encryption.
>
> VPN technology is also used by individual Internet users to secure their wireless transactions, to circumvent geo-restrictions and censorship, and to connect to proxy servers for the purpose of protecting personal identity and location.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.

You must have an account set to that country, in this case Spain or Italy
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-account/change-region

You would be able to play the game with no problems at all.

You can change it right now, BUT if you are in UK, Xbox LIVE detects that you are not in one of these designated countries by your IP address, and, therefore, you cannot download the content.

Extra: when it comes to some DLCs, it's possible to download and enjoy them. Although, with Games on Demand it's not possible.

Comment: This is completely untrue. I connect to an account created 'under a different country' all the time, to access content that is unavailable in my country.

Comment: OK, then try to download a game with this account.
DLCs are possible to download. Games on Demand are not possible.
If you want to take a chance, go ahead

Comment: Games are what I access.

Comment: @Timelord64 - do you use a VPN?

Comment: @camelCase nope.

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to do that. Since they are not in your PAL Country, you cannot access them. Sorry.